# What doesDB-15 and DB-16 in Android mean?

Tags: android

I was wondering what DB-15 and DB-16 means. I read about it concerning Android packers in several versions that are made for DB-15 and DB-16.

Comment: do you have the extract of text you read it from for context? It could be the version that has been assigned to the database. I.e. schema version

Comment: "Protection mechanisms adopted by six packers in
DB-15 and DB-16. The symbol before (or after) “—” denotes whether
a packer in DB-15 (or DB-16) uses the mechanism or not."

Comment: As far as I know, this is not Android specific, but specific to this packer app (or packer format).